# If $ \ g(u,v)=f(x(u,v), y(u,v)) \ $ , find the gradient of $ \ g \ $

Tags: calculus

If $ \ g(u,v)=f(x(u,v), y(u,v)) \ $ , find the gradient of $ \ g \ $.

**Answer:**

$ grad \ g=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} \hat i+\frac{\partial g}{\partial v} \hat j \\ grad \ g= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}  \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \hat i+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}  \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \hat j $

**Am I right ?**

Comment: I don't think you are right but I also don't know what $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ are, so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: here $ du=\hat i \ \ and \ \ dv=\hat j \ $ has been taken as unit vectors

Comment: where, in the second line, are the derivatives of $x$ and $y$ with regard to $v$, then?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is:

$$grad(g) = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u},  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \right)   $$

Where the variables $x$ and $y$ has the same name of functions $x(u,v)$.